# Get labels of distance matrix cell

Tags: r, matrix

**Data:**

I have  a distance `matrix` called **mat** with the following lables and values:

```
>mat
           179        175        176        181        249
175 147.451648                                            
176 174.527392  28.849183                                 
181 187.166092  40.007553  16.310747                      
249 194.644103  49.268129  20.637011  17.118671           
336 190.182183  44.613076  16.023090  13.697248   5.613544
```

**Problem:**

I would like to extract the row and col labels for the min value (5.613544) of the matrix.

**The expected output is something like:**

```
[1] 336 249
```

I tried to use `colnames(mat)` and `rownames(mat)` but both return `NULL`.

I know that the function `labels(mat)`is able to return the labels:

```
[1] "179" "175" "176" "181" "249" "336"
```

But here I got stuck, and cant get my head around it. Its probably something easy, sorry in advance for asking this simple question.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Here my data using `dput()`:

```
structure(c(147.451648169349, 174.527392333086, 187.166091923018, 
                194.644102830409, 190.182183344061, 28.849182654733, 40.007553207889, 
                49.2681293306533, 44.6130761331497, 16.3107466873124, 20.6370107209517, 
                16.0230895738958, 17.1186706020006, 13.6972482228087, 5.6135436361904
    ), Size = 6L, Labels = c("179", "175", "176", "181", "249", "336"
    ), Diag = FALSE, Upper = FALSE, method = "euclidean", class = "dist")
```

Comment: I edited my dput(), thanks for the comments. The matrix is the output of the function dist() (euclidean distances).

Comment: Also, `names(which(as.matrix(mat) == min(mat), arr.ind = TRUE)[, 1])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The margin names are stored in `labels(mat)` as you can see in your `dput`:

```
labels(mat)[which(lower.tri(mat),arr.ind=TRUE)[which.min(mat),]]
# [1] 336 249
```

- In a distance matrix, both margins are the same, so  `labels` are used instead of `dimnames`.
- `which.min` gives the vector position of the minimum value. However `mat` is a matrix, so...
- `which(lower.tri(mat),arr.ind=TRUE)` gives the link between matrix and vector positions.

---

*@DavidArenburg's alternative*

```
names(which(as.matrix(mat) == min(mat), arr.ind = TRUE)[, 1])
```

- `as.matrix(mat)` adopts `labels` as its `dimnames`. These names carry over to `as.matrix(mat) == min(mat)` and are kept in the result of the `which(...,arr.ind=TRUE)`.
- Because the distance matrix is symmetric, with `d(a,b)==d(b,a)`, we have two minima (assuming a unique minimizing pair of points). We can select the pair of points by taking the column positions `[,1]`, which, again, hold onto `mat`'s original `labels`, but now in its `names` attribute.

Comment: works like a charm, although the code is really confusing. :) thanks

Comment: @Frank why does `which(mat == min(mat))` give the same result as `which(mat == min(mat), arr.ind=T)`?

Comment: @plafort I'm not technically right in saying "`mat` is a matrix". Actually, it does not have a dimensions attribute (that `arr.ind=TRUE` would use to convert a vector position to an array/matrix position) and `is.matrix(mat)` is false. `lower.tri` coerces `mat` to a matrix which is why `which(lower.tri(mat),arr.ind=TRUE)` behaves correctly. Good question.

Comment: Though you can convert it to a matrix using `as.matrix(mat)` (only if you want of course)

Comment: Ah, I see your answer/comment now :) I think that would make a good answer.

Comment: It's quite similar to yours so you can add it too if you want.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Added. Feel free to improve the explanation or make other changes.

Comment: Thanks for including the second answer provided by David Ahrenburg.
I also edited my initial questions title, since my question  applies to distance matrices and not to matrices in general.